# fooTable pagination not working with laravel/angular api data

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.1, footable

I have called data with laravel api and send to footable using angularjs but the pagination not working, Is there any way to set the no of records for pagination and reload the footable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Footable](https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/tree/V2) is a jquery plugin. This means that it will be instantiated before the **Angular** can add contents as response from php.

Usually, the best way to approach this would be to instantiate the plugin *after* you have your data client-side.

My suggestion would be to create the table using the [angular directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) as, I believe, you already do and then initialize your plugin like the [documentation says](https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/tree/V2) `$('.footable').footable();` **after** you receive your data.

Comment: Same case with me. In my specific case, there were 2 reasons: 
1. I had not enclosed `$('.footable').footable();` within "on dom ready" jquery syntax `$(function() {  $('.footable').footable(); })
2. I had forgotten to create pagination region for footable (e.g. view a `.pagination tfoot`